# .NET Core - Securing vulnerable data - user's signature

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, web, cryptography

One of applications feature is keeping user's signature. My idea is to keep bytes of that signature in a database and return encoded base 64 image when is needed to be returned to a user. The application is only accessible to authenticated users and two factor authentication is required. But my only worry is how this should be kept - should I use encryption and keep encrypted bytes and when is needed decrypt bytes and return to a user? Has anybody had such a case?

Comment: Use the [Data Protection API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/using-data-protection?view=aspnetcore-5.0), which uses the user secure storage and let the OS handle this.

Comment: By signature, do you mean an image of a user's *wet signature* (i.e., an image of what a user might sign on his driver's license with a pen), or some sort of digital signature? If the former, then that image is hardly a secret. If the latter, then please tell us some details.  In either case, your application shouldn't be using it except at the direction of the user

Comment: @ckuri that's actually something - so idea would be store protected base 64 string and unprotect it when returning to end user?

Comment: @Flydog57 so it is actually a wet signature. Idea is that some worker does job and as a confirmation of his work, client makes a signature in an application (using react canvas to be exact) and this signature (bytes/string whatever )needs to be stored.

Comment: Encryption/decryption using modern standard libraries is pretty simple. The hard part is managing the key material. If you want to store something encrypted in a database, your first step is to look at what encryptiom facilities the database offers, and check to see if those mitigate what you see in your threat model.

Comment: @imaco Yes, that’s the idea. The big benefit is that you don’t need to care about key management which is the most difficult part to get right when trying to do this yourself.